# How do I prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n \Delta E)=0$ iff $1_{E_n} \rightarrow 1_{E}$ in measure $\mu$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $E_n, E \in M$. Prove that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n \Delta E)=0$ iff $1_{E_n} \rightarrow 1_{E}$ in measure $\mu$.

Can anyone suggest me some hints for this question?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that
$$E_n\Delta E =\{x\in X:|1_E-1_{E_n}|=1\}.$$
Recall that convergence in measure means that for every $\epsilon $ $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu (|1_E-1_{E_n}|>\epsilon)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for x $ \not \in E_n \Delta E$, it breaks into two cases: $x \in E_n \cap E$, in which case $|1_{E_n}(x)- 1_E(x)|= 0$, or $x \not \in E \cup E_n$, in which case $|1_{E_n}(x) - 1_E(x)| = 0$ again. Moreover, $|1_{E_n}(x) - 1_{E}(x)| = 1$ iff $x \in E_n \Delta E$. Thus, $\mu(x : |1_{E_n}(x) - 1_E(x) | \geq \epsilon) = \mu(E_n \Delta E)$ for any $\epsilon \leq 1$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Now just consult the definition of convergence in measure.